# Beginner Stuck on How to Manipulate Data Returned By Apollo/GraphQL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo, graphql-js, vue-apollo

I'm brand new to Vue so this might be a stupid question, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to manipulate the data returned by Apollo/GraphQL in my component.

This is what I'm working with:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
  name: 'HeaderPrimary',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      posts: [],
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    posts: gql`
      query posts {
        posts {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }`
  },
  components: {
    Loading_Spinner
  },
  methods: {
     checkPosts: function(){
       console.log('>> [HeaderPrimary] posts = ',posts[0])
     }
  },
  watch: {
   posts: function callback(){
    this.checkPosts();
   }
  }
```

apollo is working.. it's receiving the data fine.. but I wanted to write a function that would return the results in a console log so that I could see the results in my browser console when I npm serve. I'm also trying to understand where I can manipulate the data when it's ready.

I'm getting a lot of undefined errors.. so I started using "this" keyword because I'm still a bit unclear on how the different vue options are scoped in relation to each other.

I also realized that it's possible that "posts" is logging as undefined because the apollo query is asynchronous and may not have filled the object with data before I'm logging, so I tried to use "watch" to check when "posts" updates and then references a function in methods, but it seems to not be finding my method, and posts isn't really logging properly either.

Is this the right way to go about it? What am I doing wrong? How can I know when the data is returned and ready to be manipulated? How can I access it?